# Cross-Domain OAuth... how to get response?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm creating a Chrome Extension which will interact with a particular popular website.

It injects html into the site which adds new features. Parts of these features depend on the user being logged in, and in order to get that logged in user information, we need to to authenticate the extension with this website's OAuth authentication API.

For example, lets say the popular site (that we don't own, obviously) is `www.github.com`.

When the user is on www.github.com, our extension injects a button that says 'Connect with GitHub' on the site.

When that button is clicked, and a popup opens to Githubs OAuth API, and it asks the user: 'Do you want to give the app XYZ access to your GitHub account? Yes / No'.

Once they hit yes, our extension is authenticated and can now use the GitHub API to access information like their username and such, and inject it right into the github.com website.

All this is how we want it to work, but the problem is we're having a lot of difficulty communicating between the current window (`www.github.com`) and the popup window of our own server (`www.server.com`).

The Oauth success callback which happens in the popup, that returns the token, we can't communicate it back to the main page, because the 'protocols, domains, and ports' don't match.

What is the best way to capture that token from inside the popup oauth success window, so that we can use this token in our extension, which sits on the other domain?

Comment: Have you looked at `chrome.identity` API?

Comment: One technique ive used before is to watch for the popup  address change (actually used a new tab instead of popup mode) and capture the token from there (i.e. url contains "token=") instead of the page content, then close the window. An extension of mine used  to do this for google oauth but later i replaced it with chrome.identity

Comment: Does Firefox have something similar? I was hoping to build this so that it was agnostic to the type of extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the following: In the final stage of the auth flow you can redirect to `server.com`. Since you own `server.com` you can inject a script at the end that passes data to the extension via `window.opener.postMessage`

For example, in the final page rendered by `server.com`:

```
window.opener.postMessage({"userhash": "abc1234567890"}, '*');
```

Then register an event listener on the window in the extension

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
});
```

This should work in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: wow thats a crazy good answer, i wouldnt have thought of doing it that way

Comment: Wow that *is* a crazy answer, broadcasting it over `*`.

Comment: That's very helpful..Thanks!

Comment: I agree, DA BEST anwser ever !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't get a response because Chrome has a "Same origin policy".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Normally you can get around that by letting your www.server.com put www.github.com in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response.

See also the answer to this question for an example:
[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)